# Getting error "org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: eval is disabled" while trying to do accessibility testing using Axe-Core

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, accessibility

I am trying to do accessibility testing using Axe-Core tool using Java as the Programming language. I was able to get the result from many pages in my application but for one of the page, I am getting error as

```
 org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: eval is disabled
(Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'XXXX', ip: 'XXXX', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', 
os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 81.0.4044.138, chrome: 
{chromedriverVersion: 81.0.4044.138 (8c6c7ba89cc9..., userDataDir: C:\Users\NASEEM~1.AHM\AppDa...}, 
goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:52030}, javascriptEnabled: true, 
networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, 
proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, 
pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: cbdfe9de190b8224da1ec675bef90966
```

I am getting the above error in the code

```
 JSONObject responseJSON = new AXE.Builder(driver, scriptUrl).analyze();
```

I am getting this error while running the test in Chrome browser. I executed the same code in Firefox browser and there I was able to run it without any issue.

Anything which I should add while running the test? Any Desired Capabilities should I include?

Please suggest.

Comment: long shot as not seen this, but do you have a content security policy on the site?

Comment: Not sure about it...Is there any way I can check, please let me know. And as mentioned above, I can run the test on Firefox, it's only chrome where I am facing the issue.

Comment: yeah, look at the headers on the network tab in developer tools, you would see one called `content-security-policy:`, or it could be in the `<head>` as `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"` - drop the URL here and I will have a look if you want.

Comment: Yeah, I can see the header as content-security-policy:  with some big value...

Comment: can you copy it here

Comment: Unfortunately due to client policy, I can't paste it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is that you are getting this error as the site you are testing has a [content security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)

A Content Security Policy (CSP) allows a website owner to protect their end users by ensuring no malicious third party JS, CSS images etc. are injected into the site. Anything included in the CSP is allowed, anything not included is blocked.

Within a CSP it will block JavaScript `eval` function, which is required in your programme.

The site owner would have to explicitly allow `eval` on their site (as it is blocked by default if you have any JS rules in your CSP) by adding `unsafe-eval` as one of the rules on their CSP.

Taken from the page I linked on CSP:-

> **'unsafe-eval'**
>
> Allows the use of eval() and similar methods for creating code from
>   strings. You must include the single quotes.

The only way you could fix this is by asking the owner of the site to add that to their CSP or by changing whichever function is injecting `eval` into their site.

If you want another site to test to confirm it is CSP that is blocking your script you can try mine https://klu.io as my CSP is very strict.

### Update after conversations

It appears I got the problem correct but not the cause.

This was being caused by the website overriding `window.eval` to throw an error (basically disabling it). The following fiddle demonstrates this behaviour in it's most basic form.

```js
window.eval = function(){
    throw new Error("window.eval is disabled");
}

eval(1);
```

There isn't much you can do at this point without rewriting Axe-Core to not use `eval` as it obviously injects this into the Window being tested at some point.

The only idea I have (if someone else stumbles across this problem) to fix this would be to replace the offending script with one that has the function that overrides `window.eval` with a duplicate that has every other function cloned other than the one that blocks the script running. However if they are disabling `window.eval` then it is highly likely that they are also using a CSP and so you wouldn't be able to inject a script.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your response but how it's working in Firefox. 

Also, I checked other pages in the same application where I can see content-security-policy header as well but there I can properly run the code in Chrome browser....The issue is in this page only.

Comment: Also, I tried to run the code in your site https://klu.io/ in Chrome browser. I was able to run without any issue.

Comment: I must be wrong about it being CSP, but you defo have a problem with `eval` not being run, perhaps there is something about the particular site your are testing that requires `eval` to be run on it that is different from my site? Sorry bud, hope you find out the solution.

Comment: Just had a thought, does the site override `window.eval` somewhere in the scripts?

Comment: try typing `eval(1)` into the console and see if it runs on the site. It will run on my site if it is part of the page so `eval` is indeed allowed, I think I misunderstood the `unsafe-eval` all this time

Comment: Hey, I am getting an error "Uncaught Error: eval is disabled" while running the eval(1) from Console window...I think this should be the root cause of this issue...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213962/discussion-between-naseem-and-graham-ritchie).